# Skip foreach loop when response is empty using PDO querys in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I need to access a DB in order to store info obtained from the query as an array and push more data obtained from external sources to finally store the updated array using an API. The core of my query lies in the id of each customer, which is previously obtained from the API, using the id I launch my query to see if there is info in the DB, however not every customer has data stored in the DB and since I am sadly working directly on production, I'm afraid to test what would happen if I tried to push the empty `$newData` out of fear of screwing up (that is why I am not using the `array_push()` in the test code I will be posting below, but a `var_dump($newData)`. I've tried several things to skip the loop whenever this is the case and I am currently using another `var_dump($msg)` to test things out, but I am unable to set the right conditions, so the message never appears.

This is my query and the code that updates the aforementioned array:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT a.`zone`, b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id`, b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))/60) AS minutos, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100) AS total 
                                FROM `billing`.billing_zones a INNER JOIN cdr b 
                                ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id` 
                                WHERE source_external_subscriber_id = :source_external_subscriber_id
                                GROUP BY b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, a.`zone` 
                                ORDER BY  total desc');
        $stmt->execute(array('source_external_subscriber_id' => $source_external_subscriber_id));


        foreach ($stmt as $row) {

            $newData = [
                'name' => $row['zone'],
                'sku' => $row['source_customer_billing_zone_id'],
                'units' => $row['minutos'],
                'subtotal' => $row['total'],
                'tax' => 21,
                'account' => $account
            ];

            array_push($invoice['products'], $newData);
}
```

`$invoice` is the array I create from the API, the one I must attach the DB info to. Whenever `$source_external_subscriber_id` has entries in the DB, it works perfectly fine, but if the id is not present I don't know how to skip the loop for that id.

At this moment I've tried several things, but none seem to work since the `$msg` is never displayed:

```php
/* 1 */
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    if (!empty($row) && $row != "") {

        $newData = [
            'name' => $row['zone'],
            'sku' => $row['source_customer_billing_zone_id'],
            'units' => $row['minutos'],
            'subtotal' => $row['total'],
            'tax' => 21
        ];

        var_dump($newData);

    }else{

        $msg = "There are no entries";
        var_dump($msg);
    }

}



/* 2 */
if (!empty($stmt)) {

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {


        $newData = [
            'name' => $row['zone'],
            'sku' => $row['source_customer_billing_zone_id'],
            'units' => $row['minutos'],
            'subtotal' => $row['total'],
            'tax' => 21
        ];

        var_dump($newData);
    }
}else{
    $msg = "There are no entries";
    var_dump($msg);
}



/* 3 */
if (!is_array($stmt)) {

    $msg = "There are no entries";
    var_dump($msg); 

}else{
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        $newData = [
            'name' => $row['zone'],
            'sku' => $row['source_customer_billing_zone_id'],
            'units' => $row['minutos'],
            'subtotal' => $row['total'],
            'tax' => 21
        ];

        var_dump($newData);
    }
}
```

-UPDATE-

When trying out the third solution I thought of, it always displays `$msg` because it is not really an array: When I dump the variable the query is what appears. I have no clue on how to do this.
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I don't want to start an argument with you and I'm sure you are not interested in hearing details about my job or experience, my company uses a third party app to store the invoices (the API I must use) so I can't create a test enviroment because the only enviroment there is is one that costs 50K/year, a price I can't afford.
Thank you anyways for your help.

Comment: No, sorry If I dind't explain myself properly, whe have a third party app with an API that takes care of all the invoicing with the help of another 3rd party app. My code must get the invoices using the API (`$invoice`), use the client Id to search the db for additional products/services and if there are, add them to the invoice (`array_push()`) to finally do an update using the API. But not every customer has those extra products/services, hence the problem of `$newData` being sometimes empty. The goal is to remove the second 3rd party app from the equation.

Comment: A clear case of imaginary problem. Foreach **already** skips the loop when response is empty, your existing code already works as intended. Voting to close

Comment: I see, as I mentioned earlier, I dont have a test enviroment and I have already once screwed with the billing in the short time I've been here, so I was scared of repeating the error and did not want to try anything unless 100% sure.
I forgot to thank you for the help!

Comment: @YourCommonSense "I've tried several things, and I'd like to not experiment any further in production without at least knowing that I'm getting closer to a solution". It's perfectly fine to have tried many things and not want to try more before having a better idea of a possible solution. If you don't want to help the person, ask for clarifying details or close the question for one of the standard reasons, just move on to the next question. It's perfectly valid to want to do a specific thing if the `foreach` loop didn't have anything to iterate over.

Comment: As of the test environment that costs slightly below 50/K year, here is one: `$stmt = [];` You can test a foreach skipping an empty result using this environment. Hope you can afford this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PDOStatement`'s `rowCount` to find out if there's any hits before iterating over it:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
    foreach (...) {

    }
else
{
    print("Display error message here");
}
```

Another option is to not iterate directly over the statement, but to fetch the rows first, then decide what to do:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        ..
    }
}
else
{
    // display error message
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mats! This is the first time I am using PDO and I've only been working for 5 months as the only developer in my company. I'll test it right away and provide you with an update on how it went!